# How to get directory of the script's directory when symlinks are involved?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a ~/.bash_aliases file which I have symlinked to a file in a git repo at ~/dev/bash_scripts/bash_aliases.sh

When .bash_aliases is run, I want it to run ~/dev/bash_scripts/bash_functions.sh but I don't want to hardcode this path. I would like to avoid setting up a symlink to bash_functions.sh if possible. How do I accomplish this?

The aim:
Even if my repo is ~/dev/blah/bash_scripts, so long as I set up the symlink to bash_aliases.sh then it will be able to run bash_functions.sh that's always located in the same dir as bash_aliases.sh

EDIT: Add more detail for clarification

I want bash_aliases.sh to be able to find the path of bash_functions.sh and execute it, irrespective where it's executed from.

```
Hiro@penguin:~/dev/bash_scripts$ tree
.
├── bash_aliases.sh
└── bash_functions.sh
Hiro@penguin:~$ ls -la|grep .bash
lrwxrwxrwx   1 Hiro Hiro     49 Dec 16 11:49 .bash_aliases -> /home/Hiro/dev/bash_scripts/bash_aliases.sh
```

Comment: Symlinks work entirely on the basis of paths. You can't create a symlink to a file without knowing either the absolute path to the file or a relative path from the location of the symlink to the file.

Answer (score 0):

To get the real path without the symlink of bash_aliases.sh, you could do:

```
dirname "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
```

So then to call the script bash_functions.sh which is in that same path, you can write:

```
"$(dirname "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")"/bash_functions.sh
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives the path of wherever you executed the script from.
E.g. executing from home dir returns /home/Hiro and executing from ~/dev gives /home/Hiro/dev

Comment: Ah yes, you probably call it with `source`. ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} instead of $0 should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to allow for various special cases:

```sh
# directory original file is in
dir0="$( cd "$(dirname "$( readlink "$0" || ls -1 "$0" )")" && pwd -P )"
```

This reads any symlink else uses the real name. Then it `cd`s to that directory to get its physical path skipping any other symbolic link strangeness.

Comment: The `ls` is probably not a good idea here. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs; maybe trade it for `printf '%s\n' "$0"`

Comment: Oh, yes. In my time I"ve seen some dilly of problems caused by shell metacharacters., which is why I double quoted everything. In practice the double-quotes are good enough for sane situations. Some of my professional scripts go wilder on the defensive but I skipped that complexity here.  And thanks for the link to that well-written article I will remember.

Comment: Tried this solution but it's returning the dir of wherever the script is executed from. I.e. home dir